# Auth:login doesn't works Socialite Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite to Register my User with Facebook but after I persist the User, I cannot Log the User with Auth::login.
This is my Code:

```
 public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {

        try{
        $socialuser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
            }
        catch(\Exception $e){

            return redirect('/');
        }

        $socialProvider = SocialProvider::where('provider_id',$socialuser->getId())->first();

        if(!$socialProvider)
        {

        $user = User::where('email',$socialuser->getEmail())->first();
        if(!$user) $user = User::firstOrCreate(['email'=>$socialuser->getEmail(),'name'=>$socialuser->getName()]);
        $user->socialProviders()->create(['provider_id'=>$socialuser->getId(),'provider'=>$provider]);
        }
        else
            $user = $socialProvider->user;

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

The user is always redirect to the Login page.
Maybe it is the Session?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-social-authentication-with-socialite

Answer (score -1):

Just run

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and try again. It should work